# SQL Query in WordPress - Getting Impossible WHERE error

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't get any result in the SQL query below. I am trying to find user_id of users with custom usermeta fields.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT user_id
    FROM wp_usermeta
    WHERE (
        (
            (meta_key='user_school_subjects' AND meta_value LIKE '%history%')
            OR (meta_key='user_professional_courses' AND meta_value LIKE '%history%')
            OR (meta_key='user_language_tutoring' AND meta_value LIKE '%history%')
            OR (meta_key='user_music_tutoring' AND meta_value LIKE '%history%')
        )
        AND (meta_key='user_gender' AND meta_value='male')
    )
```

When I run the query in SQL PHPMYADMIN, I get an error -> **Impossible WHERE Query**

What's wrong with the query?
Please help me fix the error in the above query.

UPDATE:
Here is the full search query being built using a form.

```
global $wpdb;

    $user_ids = array();
    $user_query = null;

    if (isset($_REQUEST['search']) && !empty($_REQUEST['search']) ) {
        $s = $_REQUEST['search'];
        $user_query .= "((meta_key='first_name' AND meta_value LIKE '%".$s."%') OR (meta_key='last_name' AND meta_value LIKE '%".$s."%') OR (meta_key='display_name' AND meta_value LIKE '%".$s."%') OR (meta_key='user_nicename' AND meta_value LIKE '%".$s."%') OR (meta_key='user_login' AND meta_value LIKE '%".$s."%'))";
    }

    if (isset($_REQUEST['email']) && !empty($_REQUEST['email']) ) {
        $s = $_REQUEST['email'];
        if ($user_query) {
        $user_query .= " AND (meta_key='user_email' AND meta_value='".$s."')";
        } else {
        $user_query .= "(meta_key='user_email' AND meta_value='".$s."')";
        }
    }

    if (isset($_REQUEST['subject']) && $_REQUEST['subject'] !='' ) {
        $s = $_REQUEST['subject'];
        if ($user_query) {
        $user_query .= " AND ((meta_key='user_school_subjects' AND meta_value LIKE '%".$s."%')";
        $user_query .= " OR (meta_key='user_professional_courses' AND meta_value LIKE '%".$s."%')";
        $user_query .= " OR (meta_key='user_language_tutoring' AND meta_value LIKE '%".$s."%')";
        $user_query .= " OR (meta_key='user_music_tutoring' AND meta_value LIKE '%".$s."%'))";
        } else {
        $user_query .= "((meta_key='user_school_subjects' AND meta_value LIKE '%".$s."%')";
        $user_query .= " OR (meta_key='user_professional_courses' AND meta_value LIKE '%".$s."%')";
        $user_query .= " OR (meta_key='user_language_tutoring' AND meta_value LIKE '%".$s."%')";
        $user_query .= " OR (meta_key='user_music_tutoring' AND meta_value LIKE '%".$s."%'))";
        }
    }

    if (isset($_REQUEST['location']) && $_REQUEST['location'] !='' ) {
        $s = $_REQUEST['location'];
        if ($user_query) {
        $user_query .= " AND ((meta_key='user_address' AND meta_value LIKE '%".$s."%')";
        $user_query .= " OR (meta_key='user_zipcode' AND meta_value LIKE '%".$s."%'))";
        } else {
        $user_query .= "((meta_key='user_address' AND meta_value LIKE '%".$s."%')";
        $user_query .= " OR (meta_key='user_zipcode' AND meta_value LIKE '%".$s."%'))";
        }

    }

    if (isset($_REQUEST['gender']) && !empty($_REQUEST['gender']) ) {
        if ( $_REQUEST['gender'] != '') {
            $s = $_REQUEST['gender'];
            if ($user_query) {
            $user_query .= " AND (meta_key='user_gender' AND meta_value='".$s."')";
            } else {
            $user_query .= "(meta_key='user_gender' AND meta_value='".$s."')";
            }
        }
    }

    if (isset($_REQUEST['status']) && !empty($_REQUEST['status']) ) {
        if ( $_REQUEST['status'] == 'active') {
            $s = $_REQUEST['status'];
            if ($user_query) {
            $user_query .= " AND ( (meta_key='user_membership' AND meta_value='active')";
            $user_query .= " OR (meta_key='user_availability' AND meta_value='available'))";
            } else {
            $user_query .= "((meta_key='user_membership' AND meta_value='active')";
            $user_query .= " OR (meta_key='user_availability' AND meta_value='available'))";
            }
        }
        elseif ( $_REQUEST['status'] == 'inactive') {
            $s = $_REQUEST['status'];
            if ($user_query) {
            $user_query .= " AND ((meta_key='user_membership' AND meta_value='".$s."')";
            $user_query .= " OR (meta_key='user_availability' AND meta_value='unavailable'))";
            } else {
            $user_query .= "((meta_key='user_membership' AND meta_value='".$s."')";
            $user_query .= " OR (meta_key='user_availability' AND meta_value='unavailable'))";
            }
        }
    }

    if (isset($_REQUEST['nationality']) && $_REQUEST['nationality']!='any' ) {
        $s = $_REQUEST['nationality'];
        if ($user_query) {
        $user_query .= "AND (meta_key='user_nationality' AND meta_value='".$s."')";
        } else {
        $user_query .= "(meta_key='user_nationality' AND meta_value='".$s."')";
        }
    }


    if (!empty($user_query)) {
        $wp_users = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE ($user_query)"); }
```

EDIT: You can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735176/compex-mysql-left-join-using-multiple-entries-from-meta-tables

Comment: This is a MySQL question and not related to WordPress.

Answer (score 3):

Look at your conditions:

```
WHERE (
  ( 
    (meta_key='user_school_subjects'
      AND meta_value LIKE '%history%')
    OR (meta_key='user_professional_courses'
        AND meta_value LIKE '%history%')
    OR (meta_key='user_language_tutoring'
        AND meta_value LIKE '%history%')
    OR (meta_key='user_music_tutoring'
        AND meta_value LIKE '%history%')
  )
  AND (meta_key='user_gender'
        AND meta_value='male'))
```

There is no way that you can have a meta key matching one of these--

- `user_school_subjects`,
- `user_professional_courses`,
- `user_language_tutoring`,
- `user_music_tutoring`

... that also matches this--

- `user_gender`

If the key matches any of the first four, and it has to match one for that block to be true, then it automatically does not match the fifth. You can't ever get a `true` out of that. This clause is exactly what the server says-- impossible.

I would suggest [`WP_User_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) but I don't think it is capable of the logic you need.

You need to `JOIN` on the table, something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT wpmu.user_id
FROM wp_usermeta AS wpmu
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta AS gender ON wpmu.user_id = gender.user_id
WHERE (
  (
    (wpmu.meta_key='user_school_subjects'
        AND wpmu.meta_value LIKE '%history%')
      OR (wpmu.meta_key='user_professional_courses'
          AND wpmu.meta_value LIKE '%history%')
      OR (wpmu.meta_key='user_language_tutoring'
          AND wpmu.meta_value LIKE '%history%')
      OR (wpmu.meta_key='user_music_tutoring'
          AND wpmu.meta_value LIKE '%history%')
    )
    AND (gender.meta_key='user_gender'
      AND gender.meta_value='male')
  )
```

I can't swear to that 100% since I can't test it without your data, but that is the idea.

Comment: Thanks a tonne! It did give me the desired result. Now, I am wondering how to JOIN the table as I have multiple options save in the wp_usermeta table.

Comment: My code does `JOIN` the table. `JOIN` the table on what? And why? To do what?

Comment: To be very honest, I don't know a thing about SQL. So I am at loss.

Comment: If you can't explain the problem, how do expect to get an answer?

Comment: Sorry for not being descriptive. I have a list of custom fields saved in the wp_usermeta table such as user_address, user_availability and user_gender as you can see in the second code that I have pasted. I want to be able to pick a user based on a form with the inputs for all the fields. I hope I have been able to explain  my objective. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, ok, but ___what do you want to do with those?___

Comment: Managed to solve the riddle affter reading your code in detail and referring to another answer here. Many thanks for your help.